# how would you light such a scene?

Tags: light, lighting, world

I'm trying to build a light setup to get a render like this reference:

[image]

Background gradient, a lot of light on the front and quite dark and blue shadows.

But I'm not sure how to achieve it.
Eg : what type of "world" would you use ?
Would you use a gradient, or a solid color, and which one ?
What kind of lamp ? Is a sun enough ?

Well, any tip/lighting advice is welcome.
Here's what I got for know, which is not exactly what I would like to get.. :/

[image]

And my Blend [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t0b93aj5fkskztr/City3.blend?dl=1) (I got the city on [Blendswap](https://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/62619)).

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

### Final

[image: final]

### Lights

As a light use **Sun Lamp** with **Size 0**. This will make shadows completely sharp. I've also changed **Strength** to **2**.

[image: lamp]

### World

For **World** I've used simple **[Linear Gradient](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60480/how-do-i-make-the-cycles-world-background-a-vertical-gradient)** to look similar to your reference image. This will give blueish tint to whole image, but we will take care of it later.

[image: world]

### Compositing:

First of all you will need to give your objects same **Pass Index**. Take a look here how to do it: [Object ID to a whole group](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46823/object-id-to-a-whole-group).

And check **Object Index** under **Render Layers > Passes**.

[image: passes]

Now we can use our objects as mask for **Color Correction** and reduce unnecessary saturation for shadows/highlights and everything we need without affecting **World Background**.

[image: colors]

Comment: Hi LukeD, that's better; but in the reference the shadows are cleary blue, while they are grey here... any idea ? Or is it post-production ?

Comment: @gordie Mostly it's due to post-production. I'll have a look in Compositor how to achieve this effect. I'm not an specialist in that area though. It could be pretty easily be achieved in Photoshop for example.

Comment: @gordie I've reworked my answer. Check World and Compositing section.